# MS WORD - Fields - Cross reference from a word table throughout the text in rhe rest of document with returning only the values of the cell

Tags: microsoft-word

I am trying to automate a word doc

- i have a table in a word doc that when i update it i want to update the values from the table throughout the word doc in text paragraphs
- i have set the entire value of a cell within a table as a bookmark
- when I cross reference throughout the file it inserts the entire cell and not the values of the cell within the reference field
- I know if I make the values within the cell the bookmark it works however the whole point of this is that you can delete the entire values within the cell and update them
- when you do this the bookmark itself gets deleted so it doesn't allow the user to update.

I.e. is there any way to modify the Field formulas i.e = my current field code is { REF Bookmark_1}

- is there some kind of way to pull JUST the values of of bookmark_1 so a little cell doesn't get inputted???

Again i need this field in the table to be editable so i cant just bookmark the template placeholder data...

Answer (score 0):

### Try, instead of bookmarks and cross-reference fields, using Mapped Content Controls

- You can set them so they cannot be deleted, even though they can be edited and the contents deleted.
- They update instantly. They do not need manual or macro updating.
  ' They are bilateral. A change made in any copy is reflected in all copies in the document.

Here is [my reference to the 15 such controls](http://addbalance.com/word/MappedControls.htm#PageStart) built into word as so-called Document Properties. It contains a link to Greg Maxey's page on [Mapped Content Controls](http://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/mapped_content_controls.html).